# Simple MEAN Stack issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, web, mean

I have a express route; 
router.get('/uni/:**queryst**', function (req, res) {
    var choice = req.params.queryst);}

Where basically I use the **queryst** value from the URL to use it to query something in my database. On the front end, I need to have an input field where the user types the choice and hits submit and then it translates to something like /uni/valuehere on the browser and sending GET to express where it gets caught by the router I wrote above. I don't know how can I make the input field of HTML turn into a URL of the format /uni/valuehere .

As for testing the code initially I was directly typing the URL ***manually*** with the value I intended to verify to check if the data passed. Well, users are not going to type URL's directly to search, they will need a form and that is what I can't get my head around to how to turn the input field into a URL in a format /uni/WhateverTheUserHasTypedInTheFieldShouldAppearHere

Thanks in advance for the help. I am self learning the MEAN stack and have come a long way. I need support of experienced developers as I am currently stuck here.

Comment: String concatenation

Comment: on the form submit logic, can you not make a request to the server? Like var val=form['btnValue'] //whatever the user has clicked (which you will have access to) and then request({url: 'http://<url>/api/v1/uni/'+val}) ?

Answer (score 0):

While sending the request write (in controller):

```
$http.get('/uni/'+queryst).success(function(response){

    // Write code using response

});
```

While on the server side write:

```
$http.get('/uni/:queryst',function(req,res){
var choice= req.params.queryst
// Code ....

});
```